# Issue of SUM for column in DataFrame

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have CSV file with 10 columns, one of them is "invoice_amount". I import "invoice_amount" with code below:

```
df <- read_csv('C:/Users/kamsiong.ong/Desktop/CSV/( J_T ) July 2021 BC01 ( 1 ).csv', 
               col_types = cols_only(invoice_amount = col_double()))
```

Get an overview of the dataframe:

```
> str(df)
spec_tbl_df [1,039,040 x 1] (S3: spec_tbl_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ invoice_amount: num [1:1039040] 4.66 4.66 4.66 4.66 4.66 4.66 4.66 4.66 4.66 4.66 ...
 - attr(*, "spec")=
  .. cols_only(
  ..   logistics_provider = col_skip(),
  ..   account_no = col_skip(),
  ..   invoice_no = col_skip(),
  ..   ebs_keyed_in_period = col_skip(),
  ..   `pick_up date` = col_skip(),
  ..   consignment_no = col_skip(),
  ..   invoice_amount = col_double(),
  ..   status = col_skip(),
  ..   subsq_status = col_skip(),
  ..   remark = col_skip()
  .. )
 - attr(*, "problems")=<externalptr>
```

I try to sum invoice amount and I'm surprised with the result >> NA

```
sum(df$invoice_amount)
[1] NA
```

Try to sum up 10 invoice amount as follow and I got the correct result.

```
t <- slice(df, 1:10)
> sum(t)
[1] 46.6
```

Wonder what is wrong to `sum(df$invoice_amount)`?

Comment: Do you have `NA` values in the data? Try `sum(df$invoice_amount, na.rm = TRUE)`. If that doesn't work can you provide first few rows of the data using `dput(head(df, 10))`.

Comment: @RonakShah ok, it works. have been learning Python and getting rusty in R. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `sum_` from `hablar` which automatically removes the `NA`

```
library(hablar)
sum_(df$invoice_amount)
```